What's the outcome for each choice when Grace Pinch-Smedley asks me if I found the astrolabe within the lake?
I've decided to help Grace Pinch-Smedley find her family's astrolabe within the lake, but now when speaking to her, I'm given three choices of what to respond:

Choice 1:

I did - here you are.

Choice 2:

I did. And it's yours - for a price.

Choice 3:

I did. And I'm keeping it.


What's the outcome of each choice?
If I decide to keep the astrolabe, what can I do with it?

Okay, here are the outcomes for each choice:
Choice 1: “I did - here you are.”

Grace will be grateful, and you’ll receive 180 XP and a Mermaid Mask
as a reward

Choice 2: “I did. And it’s yours - for a price.”

Grace will give you 20 gold, and you’ll get a smaller amount of XP.

Choice 3: “I did. And I’m keeping it.”

You will keep the Astrolabe and earn Grace’s ire. You also get the
least amount of XP if you choose this option and make an enemy in the
process.

If you decide to keep it, Grace will be extremely angry and disappointed. In turn, you’ll get to keep the Pinch Smedley family astrolabe and receive 45 XP.
Find more here https://dotesports.com/hp/news/hogwarts-legacy-astrolabe-should-you-keep-it-or-give-it-back

Thanks. And what can I do with the astrolabe?
